# Matching a value in a Array list in java

Tags: java, arrays, matching

I am trying to match a value in a list using variable and return the list if condition matches.

result =

```
{
"drives": [{
"id": "0AEz3mOyzyCb7Uk9PVA",
"name": "Dev-zz-SFJobs-2020-10"
}, {
"id": "0AMEHi1wsq-8FUk9PVA",
"name": "Dev-zz-SFJobs-2020-11"
},
],
"nextPageToken": "~!!~AI9FV7RVoBRduLEGDhuzy0aSZShRe4uSXy20zpCBTP2LFWCXS0c"
  }
```

folderName = "Dev-zz-SFJobs-2020-10"

java code:

```
if(result.getDrives().contains(folderName))
{
return result;
} else {

}
```

I am trying above code, how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This would work for you if you are using java 8+

```
 Optional<Drives> value = result.getDrives().stream().filter(drive -> drive.getName().equals(folderName)).findAny();

if (value.isPresent()){
        return result;
    }else{

    }
```

I am expecting your model class Drive contains two variables of type string namely "id" and "name"

```
public class Drives {

private String id;

private String name;

public Drives(String id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Comment: java version "1.8.0_261"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_261-b12) 
above is my java version, hope it will work right?

Comment: @Daniel  yes that will work. If it works, please accept my answer